# How to import multiple tickers with the same line of code in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to import historical data for Closing Prices for various Stock Market indices around the world in Google Sheets. The =GOOGLEFINANCE() function is limited and it seems like you can only import one ticker at a time.

This process is very easy in Python for example, where I can just use the following code, which will give me the historical Closing prices for these various indices since 2000:

indxes = ['^GSPC', '^IXIC', '^DJI', '^OMX', '^GDAXI', '^AXJO', '^FCHI', '^HSI', '^BVSP', '^N225']

indices = web.DataReader(indxes,'yahoo', start = '01-01-2000')['Close']
indices

Does anyone have any idea about how to perform this action in Google Sheets?

Comment: best you can do in GS is put them in array {}

Answer (score 0):

#### [player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67755756/how-to-import-multiple-tickers-with-the-same-line-of-code-in-google-sheets#comment119761678_67755756):

The best you can do in Google Sheets is to put them in array {}